# How to specify a function on a link

Tags: wordpress

I am new to WordPress development. I am coming from Symfony and vanilla PHP development.

I want to assign a "route" or a function to generate an XML file for a specific post type.

I know that I can get the post information with WordPress functions like `get_post_meta`.

I don't know the how to assign a function to a link

`<a href="<what to do here>">DOWNLOAD XML</a>`.

What is the "WordPress way" to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't an Ajax call do the job?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a new in WP also. So I did this way:

1) I made a template *myxmltemplate.php* in **/wp-content/themes/mytheme/myxmltemplate.php** starting with:

```
/**
* Template Name: XML
*/
```

2) I created a page with template XML with url for example *example.com/xml/*

3) I put all my code into *myxmltemplate.php* which generates XML code I need

4) after that I can make a link like this

```
<a href="http://example.com/xml/">DOWNLOAD XML</a>
```

Maybe there is a better way to make routes with xml-generating (like in functions, but for me it's the simplest).